# TabBar icon becoming a rectangle when its state is selected

Tags: ios, swift, icons, uitabbarcontroller

I use two icons for different states `tabBarItem`.

My problem is that when tabbar is selected one icon to become a rectangle. 

I did the other icons, and they appear well. I was looking for any information not found on this topic. How can I fix it?
[image]

My code

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let triviaMainTableViewController = StoryboardManager.triviaStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TriviaMainTableViewController") as! TriviaMainTableViewController
    viewControllers = [triviaMainTableViewController]

    tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "TriviaTabBarDefault")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
    tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "TriviaTabBarSelected")
    tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -3)

    navigationBar.barTintColor = ColorManager.greenColor
}
```

Comment: My guess is that this icon isn't on a transparent background

Comment: @Paulw11 please write it as answer and I will confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have put your icon on a transparent background in order for the selection highlight to work correctly.  If the background color of the image isn't transparent it may look fine when it is not selected, but not when it is selected.